# Invalid type error while trying to create objects in Apex programming

Tags: salesforce, apex, force-ide

[Snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uab8A.png)

I am learning Apex programming and come from a Java background. I started by creating a simple Car class. I then instantiated the same under the Execute Anonymous console by writing :

Car test =new Car();

but I am getting an Invalid Type error message. I have recreated, renamed but am not sure what is causing this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is invalid. It looks like you're trying to write a method called `displayMessage()` but it has no return value the compiler is interpreting it as the constructor for the class, and "Car" does not match "displayMessage" so it's invalid.

Since you're not returning anything, change it to:

```
public void displayMessage() {
    System.debug('Hello');
}
```